# ¿como ejecutar 2 actions en un solo formulario?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Cordial Saludo,
tengo una duda espero que me puedan ayudar tengo un formulario que debe enviar unos datos a una parte y luego de eso debe enviar un correo electrónico de que los datos fueron enviados exitosa mente  esto son dos actions diferentes en un mismo formulario el problema es que solo ejecuta un action y no los dos alguien que pueda ayudarme con esto

Comment: Podrias colocar código? Aunque una idea mas simple es que al activar tu action que me imagino es un archivo .php ahi realices lo demas.

Comment: Eso no tiene sentido. ¿Por qué no verificas el resultado del primer action y ahí mismo si todo está OK mandas el email? Hacer lo contrario sería como ir a tal sitio a llevar una cosa, regresar y emprender otro viaje (2do action) para llevar otra cosa, pudiendo entregar ambas cosas en el mismo viaje.

Comment: El action del formulario solo te lleva a un lugar, no vas a poder lograr usar un formulario para 2 action.

Comment: Puedes enviar datos desde php a otro archivo php, es decir, recibes tus datos desde 1 solo action y los validas ya sea en ese archivo u en otro que haga las validaciones, luego si por algun extraño motivo quieres enviar esos datos si son validos a otro archivo php, lo puedes hacer facilmente mediante php sin necesidad de tener 2 actions, que de hecho creo que nisiquiera es posible tener 2 actions, pero es decir, no recomendaria tener 2 archivos por separado donde uno solo servira para enviar un correo, deberias tenerlo todo en un mismo archivo de php y ahi mismo validar y enviar el correo.

Comment: Tal vez es más simple, no necesitas 2 action, sólo llamar las funciones necesarias donde haces la primera parte del proceso. Y no, no necesitas forzosamente ponerlo todo en un solo archivo, para eso existen las funciones, los require e includes.

Answer (score 0):

Solo se puede utilizar un ation en dado caso podrías mandar información por el meto get mediante la etiqueta "a" esto depende de que funciones quieres realizar con tus botones

Comment: Esto debería ser comentario, no respuesta.